# Iterar repetidamente sobre un archivo csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, atom-editor

Estoy tratando de hacer un filtro de búsqueda de un archivo csv, donde el usuario ingrese los filtros para visualizar los datos que quiere iterando sobre el fichero. El código que estoy estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
import os
import math
import csv

def clear():
    os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")

def menu():
    while True:
        clear()
        print("\033[0;33m")
        print("\n\n\t\tMenu - Visualización de Datos")
        print("\t\t*****************")
        print("\033[0;32m")
        print("\n\t1 - Año")
        print("\t2 - Magnitud")
        print("\033[0;31m")
        print("\t9 - Salir")
        print("\033[0;0m")
        try:
            num = int(input("\n\tEscribe el número de tu elección: "))
            if num not in [1,2,9]:
                print("\n\t\033[0;31mNúmero inválido.  Intente de nuevo...")
                input("\n\tPresiona cualquier tecla para continuar.")
            else:
                return num
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("\n\t\033[0;31mNúmero inválido.  Intente de nuevo...")
            input("\n\tPresiona cualquier tecla para continuar.")

clear()
print("\n\n\t\t\t\tPrograma: Terremotos en México")
print("\t\t\t\t==================")
print("\033[0;36m")
print("\n\tDecripción: Programa para visualizar datos estadísticos relacionados con los")
print("\t            terremotos de magnitudes arriba de 5.5 en México.")
print("\n\t            La busqueda de datos se realiza mediante filtros, donde los datos")
print("\t            se entregan de manera tabular y en forma de gráficos.")
print("\033[0;0m")
input("\n\tPresiona cualquier tecla para continuar.")

clear()
with open ("results.tsv") as tsvF:
    reader = csv.reader(tsvF, delimiter = '\t')
    encabezado = next(reader)

    print("\n\tÍndice de Datos a Visualizar")
    for indice, col_enc in enumerate(encabezado):
        print (indice, col_enc)
    input("\n\tPresiona cualquier tecla para continuar.")
SelDatos = menu()
while SelDatos != 9:
    with open ("results.tsv") as tsvF:
        reader = csv.reader(tsvF, delimiter = '\t')
        encabezado = next(reader)


        #for indice, col_enc in enumerate(encabezado):
            #print (indice, col_enc)
        #input("\n\tPresiona cualquier tecla para continuar.")
        if SelDatos == 1:
            print("\n\tEn esta opción se puede elegir del rango de 1950 a 2018")
            while True:
                try:
                    yearini= input("\n\tDesde el año: ")
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print("\n\tPorfavor ingrese una fecha correcta...")

            while True:
                try:
                    yearfin= input("\n\tHasta el año: ")
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print ("\n\tPorfavor ingrese una fecha correcta...")

            years, magnitudes, locations = [],[],[]
            for col in reader:
                year = col[2]
                if year >= yearini and yearfin >= year:
                    years.append(year)
                    magnitud = float(col[9])
                    magnitudes.append(magnitud)
                    location = col[19]
                    locations.append(location)

            for ind in range(0, len(years)):
                print(years[ind],":", magnitudes[ind], '-', locations [ind])
            input("\n\tPresiona cualquier tecla para continuar.")

        elif SelDatos == 2:
            print("\n\tEn esta opción se puede elegir del rango de 5.5 a 9.9")
            while True:
                try:
                    magini = input("\n\tDesde la magnitud: ")
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print("\n\tPorfavor ingrese una fecha correcta...")

            while True:
                try:
                    magfin = input("\n\tHasta la magnitud: ")
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print ("\n\tPorfavor ingrese una fecha correcta...")

            magnitudes, years, locations = [],[],[]
            for col in reader:
                magnitud = col[9]
                if magnitud >= magini and magfin >= magnitud:
                    magnitudes.append(magnitud)
                    year = float(col[2])
                    years.append(year)
                    location = col[19]
                    locations.append(location)

            for ind in range(0, len(magnitudes)):
                print(magnitudes[ind],":", years[ind], '-', locations [ind])
            input("\n\tPresiona cualquier tecla para continuar.")

    clear()
    with open ("results.tsv") as tsvF:
        reader = csv.reader(tsvF, delimiter = '\t')
        encabezado = next(reader)

        print("\n\tÍndice de Datos a Visualizar")
        for indice, col_enc in enumerate(encabezado):
            print (indice, col_enc)
        input("\n\tPresiona cualquier tecla para continuar.")
    SelDatos = menu()

print ("Adios")
```

Con este código, el primer `print(years[ind],":", magnitudes[ind], '-', locations [ind]` sí funciona, pero en el print de `print(years[ind],":", magnitudes[ind], '-', locations [ind])` no me muestran los datos como lo hace el primero.